# I am switching domain to new server, but want to keep secure functionality on old server

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, https, legacy

I have an old legacy website that I have migrated to wordpress.

Some of the functionality will remain on the old server and be accessed via IP address, however this functionality requires a secure http connection and our current certificate is valid for the domain name which is being switched across.

I have added a redirect using mod_write to our htaccess file

```
Redirect /mySecurePage https://99.99.99.99/mySecurePage
```

However a warning is presented to user as certificate is registered to the domain name - the same domain name which now points to different ip (insecurely, and redirects to secure page on old server/different ip).

What is the best solution ?

I have full access to both servers, but wanted to avoid transferring the old functionality across to new server - its a right mess. Can I change the certificate, or do some fancy url rewriting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a subdomain legacy.yourdomain.com and let this subdomain serves as the old legacy website.

Then replace the IP in the "Redirect" rule with the subdomain you created.

Comment: OK, I think I understand, thats very clever.

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if he has a wildcard certificate for the domain. If the cert is for www.localtest.me than redirecting the request to legacy.localtest.me still throws the SSL warning.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I do have a wildcard certificate, it looks like it saved me a lot of headache. This answer is one of the best answers I have received on stack sites, I love the lateral thinking.

Answer (score 0):

**Redirect**

You can use the Redirect Option as already mentioned.  You are correct that you will need to use a SSL certificate that matches the old domain exactly.

Often two single SSL certificates are cheaper than a wildcard.

**Proxy Method**

You can use a SSL Proxy on your new server to proxy traffic to the old system.

See the ProxyPass directives.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Also don't forget:
SSLProxyEngine On 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyengine

Unless you want to not add a new domain, I would opt for the redirect version. It is a much less complicated and simple implementation.

If the site is for internal use, just buy a cheap SSL certificate for that legacy domain.